# MVC Action Attribute that checks parameter has value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a handful of Actions in my ASP.NET MVC site that have one parameter. The first lines of code on all these actions checks that the parameter is not null, and if it is, redirect to a page that allows them to choose a value for the parameter.

For example:

```
    public ActionResult Summary(string client)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(client))
            return RedirectToAction("Select");

        return View();
    }
```

I'd like to create an attribute that does something like the above code, so I don't have to repeat it in every action. Something like:

```
    [ClientRequired]
    public ActionResult Summary(string client)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And then the ClientRequiredAttribute would check the value of the client parameter, and if it's empty/null, redirect to the select client page. Is such an attribute possible?

-shnar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

It would be something like this:

```
public class ClientRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        object parameter = null;
        filterContext.ActionParameters.TryGetValue("client", out parameter);
        var client = parameter as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(client))
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RequestContext);

            var url = urlHelper.Action("Select", "ControllerName");

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Not tested, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC 5 you can use attribute routing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

```
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    // eg: /reviews
    [Route("reviews")] 
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }
    // eg: /reviews/5
    [Route("reviews/{reviewId}")] 
    public ActionResult Show(int reviewId) { ... }
    // eg: /reviews/5/edit
    [Route("reviews/{reviewId}/edit")] 
    public ActionResult Edit(int reviewId) { ... } 
}
```